# cloning form elements in jQuery without carrying over user-input data

Tags: jquery, forms, clone

I have a form with repeatable sets of inputs. I want to clone the set (class='repeatableItemInfo') while NOT retaining the data that the user enters. The following does a good job of that:

```
var subform = $('.repeatableItemInfo').clone(true);

    $('#addMore').click(function() {

    subform.appendTo('#itemInfo');

});
```

The nasty wrinkle is that one of the repeatable form fields is a "select" list with a "change" event linked to it. The code above reproduces the "select" item, but not its associated event (despite the "true" argument).

If I pop the first line into the function like this:

```
$('#addMore').click(function() {

    var subform = $('.repeatableItemInfo').clone(true);

    subform.appendTo('#itemInfo');

});
```

Then the "change" event carries over properly, but so does the data that the user has entered.

Can anyone help me get the behavior without the data?

Comment: Have you tried passing true as the second argument to clone()?

As of 1.5, the jQuery docs give you a second argument to clone().  

.clone( [withDataAndEvents] [, deepWithDataAndEvents] )

Comment: Tried that just now. No change.

Comment: how do you bind your change event to your select list?  with an `onchange` attribute?  `jQuery.bind`?

Comment: $('.itemType').change(function() { etc. });

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that you're binding the change event on the select **after** the `clone()`. That's the only thing I see that can explain it (`clone(true)` implies `clone(true,true)` by the way)

So, I don't know how your code is organized, but try to fix the problem by cloning after binding events. You can also do:

```
var subform = null;
setTimeout(function() { subform = $('.repeatableItemInfo').clone(true); }, 0);
```

which simply queues up the cloning, without delay.

Comment: clone(true) falling back to clone( true, true) makes sense as it's pretty much the jQuery way of doing everything. Thanks for bringing it forth.

Answer (score 0):

A couple general observations, based on assumptions I had to make from what code your question provided:

You should have a hidden parent element that contains the element with the desired default values be the item you want cloned.  From the looks of your code, you're using a class selector to grab the element to clone.  Having a hidden element with an id will ensure you're cloning the correct element.

```
$("#idOfParentTemplateElement .repeatableItemThing").clone().appendTo("#itemInfo");
```

You should use [jQuery.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [jQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to wire up your change event, instead of using the `onchange` attribute or `jQuery.Bind`.  You can give your select list a class and then bind items with that class name to do something special.

```
$("#itemInfo").on("change", ".class-for-special-event-thing", specialEventThingFunction)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have a clean hidden set of elements to clone? To solve the event handler issue you could make sure your event handler is using .live that way any new selects that are cloned are picked up as they are added.

Comment: Using .live seems to have helped. When I click the #addMore button, I now get a set blank set of form fields that still have their intended functionality. Sadly, this only works once and then clicking #addMore has no effect.